# How to transform value in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to change the value I'm sending. An example of a array is:

```
0: {name: "One", value: 1}
1: {name: "Two", value: 2}
2: {name: "One", value: 3}
3: {name: "Two", value: 4}
```

Not important how length array can be. Any time is four object any time only two example:

```
0: {name: "One", value: 1}  
1: {name: "Two", value: 4}
```

Important is to need to convert value inside object

If I got:

```
0: {name: "One", value: 1}
1: {name: "Two", value: 2}
2: {name: "One", value: 3}
3: {name: "Two", value: 4}
```

I need to convert to

```
0: {name: "One", value: 'Value one'}
1: {name: "Two", value: 'Value two'}
2: {name: "One", value: 'Value three'}
3: {name: "Two", value: 'Value four'}
```

What i try:

```
data: convert(ArrayOfData)


convert(arr){
    const convertArr = ['Value one', 'Value two', 'Value three', 'Value four'];
    return value.map((value: any) => convertArr[value]);
    }
```

This no work i don't know why....

second try also no work....

```
 convert(arr){
  let resultArr = arr.map(arr => { 
   if (arr.value == 1) { 
     return  'Value one'
  }
   if (arr.value == 2) {
     return 'Value two'
   } 
 })
 return resultArr;
}
```

But according to the code, this should really work ...

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have a misunderstanding about [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
const convertArr = [, 'Value one', 'Value two', 'Value three', 'Value four'];

value.map(({ name, value }) => ({
  name,
  value: convertArr[value],
}));
```

Comment: Friend with   value: convertArr[value] no work propertly but with   value: convertArr[value -1 ] work good. Why what is problem ?

Comment: Notice that `const convertArr = [ , 'Va....]`, the length is **5**

Comment: In this way, we don't need to `-1` every time it traverses, and `index` also corresponds to its value

Comment: Which way is better ?

Comment: Of course the current may, which reduces a little bit of calculation

Answer (score 0):

```js
const values = {
  "1": "one",
  "2": "two",
  "3": "three",
  "4": "four",
};

const arr = [
  { name: "One", value: 1 },
  { name: "Two", value: 2 },
  { name: "One", value: 3 },
  { name: "Two", value: 4 },
];

const result = arr.map(({ name, value }) => {
  return { name, value: `Value ${values[value]}` };
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

See the docs about [array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

> The map() method creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

Since your provided function is always returning a string you'll get an array of strings. To get what you want you need instead to return a new item where the `value` property is changed the a string 'Value one' etc.

```
function convert(arr){
  let resultArr = arr.map(item => { 
   if (item.value == 1) { 
     return  {...item, value:'Value one'}
  }
   if (item.value == 2) {
     return  {...item, value:'Value two'}
   } 
 })
 return resultArr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public someFunc() {
    let arr = [{ name: 'One', value: '1' }, { name: 'Two', value: '2' }];
    arr = arr.map((item) => {
      item.value = `Value ${item.name.toLowerCase()}`;
      return item;
    });
  }
```

However you originally have value as a number and then convert it to a string, there will be a conflict.
Also instead of my logic you can add any other logic, it should do